# Recursively locating a UIElement with InnerText in C#

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

I have a number of HTMLDIV on a page and I am trying to locate a particular one using the

```
UIElement.getProperty("InnerText")
```

The problem is I never know how many children the DIV will have and how many levels down the element will be.  So I though recursion would work for this situation rather than nested FOREACH statements.  However as my DIVS do not have a .NAME property populated and `.GetType` is always 'HTMLDIV' I don't know how to access the `.Innertext` of the child element.  I was going to use this type of method:

```
    ControlTypeIWantToFind result = 
                FindVisualChild<ControlTypeIWantToFind>(myPropertyInspectorView);

public static T FindVisualChild<T>(DependencyObject depObj, string strMyInnerText) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (depObj != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
            if (child != null && child is T)
            {
                return (T)child;
            }

            T childItem = FindVisualChild<T>(child);
            if (childItem != null) return childItem;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

But I think I need something like this:

```
if (child != null && child.innerText == strMyInnerText)
```

I hope that all makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

In one place I used code based on that below. It finds all `InnerText` items.

```
someControl.SearchProperties.Add("InnerText", "", PropertyExpressionOperator.Contains);
UITestControlCollection colNames = someControl.FindMatchingControls();
```

In another place I used:

```
string s = "";  // In case there is no InnerText.
try
{
    s = control.GetProperty("Text").ToString();
}
catch ( System.NotSupportedException )
{
    // No "InnerText" here.
}
```

The exception is not documented with [GetProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.uitesting.uitestcontrol.getproperty.aspx), I think I found it when calling the method on controls that did not have an `InnerText`. I could not find any `TryGetPropertyMethod`, but it would be easy to write your own.

---

I also used code based on this recursive routine to visit all the controls in the hierarachy.

```
private void visitAllChildren(UITestControl control, int depth)
{
    UITestControlCollection kiddies = control.GetChildren();

    foreach ( UITestControl kid in kiddies )
    {
        if ( depth < maxDepth )
        {
            visitAllChildren(kid, depth + 1);
        }
    }
}
```